# Can I configure the compiler in Visual Studio to give warnings / errors for all non-localized strings?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, localization, compiler-warnings

I would like the compiler to detect all non-localized strings in my solution.  This means any string in an .aspx or .cs file that doesn't come from a resource file.

Comment: `<div>...</div>` is a non-localized string.  This is basically impossible for ASPX.

Comment: Resharper 5 find these, (but not for aspx files as well).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010's Code Analysis can do this.  (Although not for ASPX files)